# SQL, Arithmetic with dependent subqueries

Tags: sql, math, subquery

I'm writing a query that seems overly complicated.
I need something like this:

```
SELECT (A - B - C) * -1
FROM
( 
SELECT(SELECT T1.ACCOUNT_BALANCE FROM TABLE1A T1 WHERE T1.ACCOUNT_BALANCE > 3.00  ) AS A,
SELECT(SELECT T2.ACCOUNT_BALANCE FROM TABLE1A T2 WHERE T2.EFFDT < T1.EFFDT ) AS B,
SELECT(SELECT T3.ACCOUNT_BALANCE FROM TABLE1A T3 WHERE T3.EFFDT < T1.EFFDT AND ...) AS C
) AS SOMETHING_A
```

But B and C both depend on subquery A. Or in other words, the EFFDT for B and C must be < EFFDT for A.
I don't believe you can just write

```
WHERE B.EFFDT < T1.EFFDT
```

Edit: It's all from the same table.
So something like:

```
ACCOUNT_NUM-----EFFDT------ACCOUNT_BALANCE
```

Is this enough?

Comment: include sample data, and better table structure?

Comment: I would be quite surprised if the logic suggested by your query is actually the right logic that you really want.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?  Also, you should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. There are probably many records in table1a, some of which having a balance greater than 3. So do you want for each such record to subtract all balances of the records with a smaller EFFDT? And some of these even twice? That doesn't sound likely. So give us sample table data and the desired results.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

In most DBMS's, you can do this with common table expressions.

Eg.

```
WITH a AS (SELECT c1 FROM table1)
, b AS (SELECT c1 from a)
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON (...)
```

If this doesn't answer your question, you should probably be a little more explicit as to what you're trying to accomplish. Ie., at least include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is outer apply.

```
SELECT (A.qty - B.qty - C.qty) * -1
FROM
(SELECT ACCOUNT_BALANCE FROM TABLE1A T1.... ) AS A,
outer apply(SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE things.fromA) AS B,
outer apply(SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE things.fromAorB) AS C
```

Essentially, outer apply allows you to select records for a row using WHERE clauses that use records already returned in the same row.

Comment: Thanks! Added a new answer thing below (I don't know how to put code into these comment boxes)

Answer (score 0):

The closest that I could imagine that you want with the query is something like this:

```
SELECT (t1.ACCOUNT_BALANCE -
        (SELECT SUM(T2.ACCOUNT_BALANCE)
         FROM TABLE1A T2
         WHERE T2.EFFDT < T1.EFFDT
        ) -
        (SELECT SUM(T3.ACCOUNT_BALANCE)
         FROM TABLE1A T3
         WHERE T3.EFFDT < T1.EFFDT . . .
        )
       ) * -1
FROM table1a t1;
```

However, this seems far from what one would really want on a real database.  For instance, there is no correlation on the account, which seems likely for an account-based structure.

Because this question already has answers, I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data and desired results.  You should also explain *in English* the logic that you want.  Sample code is also fine, but it should be supplemented with an explanation of what the code should do.  Also, a SQL Fiddle is really useful.

I don't recommend that you edit this question, because it already has answers and the edits might invalidate them -- drawing future downvotes.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed it to do. I had something similar before but had syntax errors. Thank you!